# Set a default row prefetch in SQL Server using JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have an application where I want to define the default number of rows to prefetch for a connection, using for both Oracle and SQL Server drivers. The Oracle driver has a the `OracleConnection` interface, which provides the `setDefaultRowPrefetch` method to do it, but I didn't find anything equivalent for the SQL Server driver.

There is a method to define the default row prefetch for a connection using the SQL Server JDBC driver?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual ways to set row fetch size are:

1. Via **`java.sql.Connection`** vendor implementation class **custom method** (e.g. `OracleConnection.setDefaultRowPrefetch`)
2. Via **`java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize(int)`**: gives a hint to the driver as to the row fetch size for all `ResultSets` obtained from this `Statement`.  This method is inherited by `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement`.  Most JDBC drivers support it.
3. Via **`java.sql.ResultSet.setFetchSize(int)`**: gives a hint to the driver as to the row fetch size for all this `ResultSet`.

MS SQL Server JDBC driver does not support any of these ways:

1. MSSQL driver has no such a method.
2. Unfortunately, while most drivers respect the hint, the MSSQL driver does not. So not useful for you.  See [What does Statement.setFetchSize(nSize) method really do in SQL Server JDBC driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318354/what-does-statement-setfetchsizensize-method-really-do)
3. Same problem as `Statement`.

By default it retrieves *all* the rows from database unless you specify cursor type in the JDBC driver. MSSQL driver can't directly control the fetch size using the usual methods.

**Solutions:**

- Cast your `Statement` to `SQLServerStatement` and use the method `setMaxRows(int)`.  Why they didn't implement this within the standard method [Steve Ballmer](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lqzaz1tNoz1qzkqhi.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/steve%2520ballmer&h=262&w=350&sz=11&tbnid=ak2TvZnMnRH8LM:&tbnh=80&tbnw=107&zoom=1&usg=__KjSV0eUmtcZvsCEnIS8_6YsIRLs=&docid=vEFAfBz2chaT3M&sa=X&ei=1M-BUd3TG8uuiQeF84H4Bg&ved=0CIIEEP4dMDc) only knows ;^)
- Create your driver with a cursor type.  The default fetch size for a cursor is 1.  Set the `Connection` string property `selectMethod=cursor`. Alternatively, you can create the `Statement` with `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.TYPE_SS_SERVER_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY` scrollability for forward-only, read-only access, and then use the `setFetchSize` method to tune performance.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342344%28SQL.90%29.aspx
- Use (proprietary) SQL to limit the number of rows returned (**not the same thing as setting the fetch size**): `SET ROWCOUNT` or `SELECT TOP N`
- Switch to open source **jTDS** driver, specially made to overcome the problems of the SQL Server driver.  It's a superior driver.

Comment: startlingly, postgres also allows you to pass a paramter in the connection string as well: `&defaultRowFetchSize=XX` (but note that's not enough, you also have to either set autocommit off by default (another query param) or vary it off for it to "take", oddly...