# Does really blockfactor with cfquery enhances the performance in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfquery

I am having a table having 360369 no of rows. I am using **SQL SERVER**.

Today when i tried a simple select statement with cfquery and blockfactor,I did not find any performance enhancement.

Moreover the performance reduced.

1. Without blockfactor , the execution time was **120884**.
2. With blockfactor, the execution time became **144003**.

As per the definition of blockfactor, my maximum row size was 437bytes ,so

**blockfactor = 32k/437 = 32768/437 = 74.9**

So I have used the blockfactor as 74 or 75.

But I did not find any performance enhancement.

Comment: Check this blog http://www.bennadel.com/blog/338-ColdFusion-CFQuery-BlockFactor-Is-Not-Impressing-Me.htm it may give you some clues.

Comment: Yes already checked,i also found the same issue no performance enhancement with blockfactor.

Comment: How much time have you run this query? you don't always see the speed difference in a query if you only run it once... Which version of SQL server do you have? which driver do you use to get connected to your database?

Comment: 1. I have executed for around 5-10 times. 2. MS SQL SERVER 2008 3.Mircrosoft SQL SERVER

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy according to cf documentation it might not be supported by some database check documentation on  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html

Comment: yes that might be the reason, in some other blogs also i found 'blockfactor' is mainly supported by Oracle.

Comment: I have never really used it, but I remember the [same question](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/251006) came up a few years ago. From my limited tests, that setting seemed to control the [fetchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378591%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) hint, and it only had an affect when using `selectMethod=cursor` (server side cursor) in the dsn. See [Set a default row prefetch in SQL Server using JDBC driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074037/set-a-default-row-prefetch-in-sql-server-using-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start changing that when you're seeing a build-up of wait time (bottle neck) for SQL server to answer the request over the network cards. If your network cards are "idle" you'd not see a difference