# Can JDBC client execute SET ARITHABORT ON on Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-optimization

Can I set Microsoft SQL Server 2012 options such as `ARITHABORT` programmatically from a (remote) Java client that uses Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0? I've noticed that `statement.execute("SET ARITHABORT ON")`returns `false` and the expected effect seems missing, hence the question.

Comment: Read the JavaDocs for `Statement.execute()`. The return value indicates if the statement generated a `ResultSet` not if the statement was successful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've read the JavaDocs before posting the question and concluded that I currently cannot know from the return value whether the statement was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I set Microsoft SQL Server 2012 options such as ARITHABORT programmatically from a (remote) Java client that uses Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0?

It certainly appears so. The code

```java
package com.example.sqlservertest;

import java.sql.*;

public class SqlServerTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;"
                + "databaseName=myDb;" + "integratedSecurity=true";
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT CONVERT(INT, SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT'))")) {
                    rs.next();
                    System.out.println(String.format(
                            "SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') is %d",
                            rs.getInt(1)));
                }
                String sql = "SET ARITHABORT ON";
                System.out.println(sql);
                stmt.execute(sql);
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT CONVERT(INT, SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT'))")) {
                    rs.next();
                    System.out.println(String.format(
                            "SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') is %d",
                            rs.getInt(1)));
                }
                sql = "SET ARITHABORT OFF";
                System.out.println(sql);
                stmt.execute(sql);
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT CONVERT(INT, SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT'))")) {
                    rs.next();
                    System.out.println(String.format(
                            "SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') is %d",
                            rs.getInt(1)));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```

returns

```
Connection established.
SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') is 0
SET ARITHABORT ON
SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') is 1
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') is 0
```

The ARITHABORT state should remain in effect for the life of the connection unless some other code changes it.