# Java JDBC SQL Server 2017 taking too long to connect

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I've just recently installed MS SQL Server 2017 on my machine, and I'm facing this issue where just opening the connection is taking too long.

this line alone takes 5.5 seconds: con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test
{
    static
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {

        Connection con = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=BSSGI;user=bssuser;password=123456";
            long startTime, endTime, total;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            total = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Con:" + total);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        finally 
        {
            con.close ();
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the output that I'm getting:

```
run:
Con:5582
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I am able to connect to the server through MS SQL Management Studio fine and I dont see any issue with query speed or connectivity.
The server is currently run on a powerful machine, and an nvme SSD (Samsung 970 pro); so I doubt it's a machine's performance issue. 
And the test program and the server are on the same machine, so I doubt it's got anything to do with network.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501791/why-does-microsoft-sql-server-2012-query-take-minutes-over-jdbc-4-0-but-seconds

Comment: Enable trace logs on the jdbc driver
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc: TRACE