# JDBC fetchSize and setAutoCommit false relationship

Tags: java, performance, jdbc

I want to know is there any inter relationship between autocommit and fetchsize in JDBC. I checked, all my connection is autocommit = true. I have set fetch size is 100. Is it correct? I want to know fetch size is working or not?

In my application am handling 500k record using a single db connection in SQL server or Oracle DB. So, what is the recommended fetch size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682614/how-to-read-all-rows-from-huge-table

Answer (score 0):

setFetchSize is not always supported by your driver so you might need to check the implementation, and generated SQL, to determine if it is being applied

Comment: How to check whether fetch size is affected or not? I am using normal JDBC implemenation

Comment: This is a good guide https://webmoli.com/2009/02/01/jdbc-performance-tuning-with-optimal-fetch-size/

Comment: I am using "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" to get the connection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074037/set-a-default-row-prefetch-in-sql-server-using-jdbc-driver

Comment: You mention both oracle and sql server in your question

Comment: Yes. Please consider now MSSQL