# How to get large data with JDBC and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, playframework

I'm trying to fetch millions data from my table, and I'm using Java Play Framework 2.0 but there is some issue. When I set limit to my query it works well and if I ask for all the data it throws error like

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: No, we cannot, as long as you don't provide some details, such as a snippet of code where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the manual:

> *By default the driver collects **all** the results for the query at once. This can be inconvenient for large data sets so the JDBC driver provides a means of basing a ResultSet on a database cursor and only fetching a small number of rows*

(emphasis mine)

The manual describes in detail how to configure the driver to not load everything into memory:
http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: What if I want to fetch all the rows?

Comment: @Sadik: I don't understand that question. Just loop through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize may help depending upon your database. I am not familiar with Play Framework but you can set fetch size with JDBC.

See [What does Statement.setFetchSize(nSize) method really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318354/what-does-statement-setfetchsizensize-method-really-do)