# MySQL and Java: Difference between fetch size and batch limit

Tags: java, mysql

I got this doubt when I was modifying a code for doing batch update for MySQL retrieval using Java.
My understanding is that fetch size is the maximum number of rows in a ResultSet object and Batch Limit is the number of select/insert/update queries that can be added to a batch, for batch execution. Can anyone correct me if I am wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Reading this link also helped me: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html. Please consider this post [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098247/jdbc-select-batching-fetch-size-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct. However to add to it  [javadoc of Statement#setFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29)

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be
>   fetched from the database

Whereas the batch limit is something which is related to how many rows you can insert or update something related to [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)

**On a side note:**

You may also check the [JDBC API implementation notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) as a good read

> **ResultSet**
>
> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory.
>   In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate, and due to
>   the design of the MySQL network protocol is easier to implement. If
>   you are working with ResultSets that have a large number of rows or
>   large values, and cannot allocate heap space in your JVM for the
>   memory required, you can tell the driver to stream the results back
>   one row at a time.

Comment: I thought we can use fetchSize with MySQL tables in Java as mentioned in here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318354/what-does-statement-setfetchsizensize-method-really-do-in-sql-server-jdbc-driv). Could you please clarify.

Comment: @user1930402:- Indeed we can use it but that is just to give a hint as the doc specifies.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this.

Comment: @user1930402:- You are welcome. You can use it this way like: `PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(qry);
stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
stmt.executeQuery();`