# How to pass parameters to hibernate in Spring 4.3.4 and Hibernate 5.2.5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I was trying to enable hibernate batch insert and updates, but no matter where I put the parameters they didn't seem to ever take affect. My Spring configuration is mostly just XML. We're using `Spring 4.3.4`, `Hibernate 5.2.5`, `Spring Data 1.10.5`, and `MySQL Connector 5.1.38`

My MySql Connection string is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME_HERE?autoReconnect=true&useTimezone=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

My jpaContext.xml has this in it (I'm omitting the whole thing, and just including the parts where I set the parameters)

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" primary="true">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates" >true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" >400</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" >true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JpaPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates" >true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" >400</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" >true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My persistance.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.session_factory.interceptor" value="com.siftit.startup.HibernateInterceptor" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="400"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="warehousePersistenceUnit"/>
</persistence>
```

The reason for the duplicated parameters in each area is that I was trying to figure out where they belonged, but no matter where I put them they didn't seem to work.

Here's the hibernate logging output for the configuration:

```
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - SessionFactory name : null
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): enabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Statistics: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Default entity-mode: pojo
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Allow initialization of lazy state outside session : disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Using BatchFetchStyle : LEGACY
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Default batch fetch size: -1
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Default null ordering: NONE
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - multi-tenancy strategy : NONE
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - JTA Track by Thread: enabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Query language substitutions: {}
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - JPA query language strict compliance: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Named query checking : enabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Second-level cache: enabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Second-level query cache: disabled
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Second-level query cache factory: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCacheFactory@2033240a
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Second-level cache region prefix: null
18:38:03,975 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Optimize second-level cache for minimal puts: disabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Second-level cache direct-reference entries: disabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Automatic eviction of collection cache: disabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - JDBC batch size: 15
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: enabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Scrollable result sets: enabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Wrap result sets: disabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - JDBC result set fetch size: null
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Connection release mode: ON_CLOSE
18:38:03,991 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG                         org.hibernate.cfg.Settings: - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
```

Everything I've tried so far has failed, and it seems like I must be doing something stupid, because everyone else's seems to work, but so far I've had no luck.

Comment: And what makes you think that is doesn't work? Your `persistence.xml` contains 2 persistence units. One with and one without batching. I would suggest just to completely remove the `persistence.xml` you don't need it with Spring. The properties on the `JpaTransactionManager` are best removed and only leave those on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`. Now are you sure you are actually using this configuration and spring configured instance or are you creating a new one in your code?

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the config logging was duplicated, and I was looking at the other persistent unit, and the values were being passed through. Thanks for the info, I'll remove the unneeded data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want efficient inserts and updates there are at least two things you need to do.

Make sure all your entities use TableGenerated ids

```
@TableGenerator(name="USER_GENERATOR", table="SEQUENCE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME",
        valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue="USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "USER_GENERATOR")
```

If you use auto increment for id generation, each insert must it own SQL string, and JPA will need to do select `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the auto increment id, after each insert. My Guess is that `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` is simply ignored by the driver.

I have not tried this with the newest MySQL JDBC driver, but a few years ago, you needed to tell the driver to rewrite the batch statements, by including `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` on JDBC URL. If you did not do that, you may get many Inserts in a batch, but every insert will include all columns names, and you will not get the benefit of `Insert into Table (columns...) Values (values..., values..., )`

**Edit:**
According to the MySQL [JDBC documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098820/2433323) there are only two valid options, read all rows into the result set up front, or read the rows using a cursor one row at the time. My Guess is that `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` is simply ignored by the driver.

Comment: Well the core issue I have right now is that hibernate isn't honoring the parameters I'm passing in, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` Will configure batching on the underlying JDBC connection used by Hibernate.

Along with this you need to implement some way to batch and execute your updates/inserts.

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
int batchSize = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    Person person = persons.get(i);
    em.persist(person);
    if(i % batchSize == 0) {
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }
 }
em.flush();
em.clear();
```

Comment: Well the core issue I have right now is that hibernate isn't honoring the parameters I'm passing in, and I can't figure out why.