# Sql Server JDBC driver pagination

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using the latest(sqljdbc42) SQL Server JDBC driver available for [official download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774). The SQL Server source dbs can vary from 2008 to 2016.

I flipped through several [existing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318354/what-does-statement-setfetchsizensize-method-really-do-in-sql-server-jdbc-driv) about [setFetchSize(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-) and it seems :

1. If there are 1000 rows and the fetch size is 100, the result set will have only 100 records in memory, at a time and will make 10 network trips to fetch the next 100 records, when rs.next() is called
2. It's unclear whether the SQL Server JDBC driver honors the fetch size

I am writing a custom library for our internal use. It will select all the data from specific tables, iterate over the results and write it to a stream. I get an OutOfMemoryError when I try to run it for several tables(each one with thousands to hundred thousand rows) but when not if I am iterating over a single table with several thousand rows. I suspect somewhere, a large table is causing the issue.

While I will continue to debug my code, I wish to know if the setFetchSize(...) really works with the latest SQL Server jdbc driver.

Note : The table is NOT having any incremental columns/surrogate keys on which I can manually paginate, I need something out-of-box

*****Edit-1*****

As specified in the comment by @a_horse_with_no_name, I think 'responseBuffering=adaptive' should be explicitly specified and the [document specifies some ways to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties). The challenge is :

1. I receive a custom DB connection pool instance as an argument and I have to use it to get a Connection object, thus, there is no way I can specify 'responseBuffering=adaptive' in the db connect URL or else where. All I get is a Connection object for usage
2. The only relevant(?) method I can use is [setClientInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo(java.util.Properties))(...) but I am unsure if that would help

Comment: If you really want to know: dive into the source code of the driver: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-adaptive-buffering

Comment: What fetch size are you using specifically?

Comment: fetch size : 1000